# mxnet infer_shape_entry TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, mxnet

I met an infer_shape error when I test my custom operator.

Error Message:

```
Error in <my_operator_name>.infer_shape: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/anaconda2/envs/mx110-py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mxnet/operator.py", line 658, in infer_shape_entry
    array('I', rshape[i])),
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Have anyone met the same problem before? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found it's because __init__ function of mxnet.operator.CustomProp only accept string type arguments.